# Unable to open modules page

Tags: views, 7, theming

This is all weird, I am unable to open the modules page, I don't understand why. I am trying to update the drupal so disabled some of the none core modules and pressed on save configuration.And now I am unable to open the modules page.Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you want to update, you should put your site in maintenance mode first. And then try to stay calm and clear cache.

Comment: vic, drupal does that by default when we load update.php. But here I did nothing but disabling some modules.

Comment: Whats your enviroment, ? and what version are you running, I would say you should try with a new drupal build, I cannot replicate the error

Comment: Can you clear Drupal cache?! Can you use drush?

Comment: Maybe check your htacess file, and what does the apachelog tell you?, if you cannot see the modules folder, it smells like a permission issue

Comment: ok, I don't know if it was the problem with server, I was able to open it after some time enabled all the modules and saved them and cleared the cache, it's working fine now except that it is taking like 10 seconds to load (Is that common?)